# Python encoding issue through sockets

Tags: python, sockets, encoding, utf-8

I am creating a short python script which requires me to send text back and forth between two computers via sockets. Now when I try to test my application locally on the same computer using telnet and it requires me to use the 'utf-8' encoding when I use the bytes() function as such:

```
connection.sendall(bytes("Unknown command", 'UTF-8'))
```

All works well locally, but when I try to test my application remotely on a raspberry pi and connect my computer through telnet I get the following error

```
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

After a bit of research I found that if I remove the utf encoding it will work remotely as such:

```
connection.sendall(bytes("Unknown command"))
```

But then this causes an error when I test locally. It says I must use an encoding. Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you confirm the Python version on each device? I think you are using Python 3 but the Pi is using Python 2. In Python 2 (later) bytes -> str.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using two different versions of python `py2 vs 3`.

Python2:

```
In [1]: bytes("Unknown command", 'UTF-8') 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ddc681192da0> in <module>()
----> 1 bytes("Unknown command", 'UTF-8')

TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Python3:

```
In [1]: bytes("Unknown command", 'UTF-8')
Out[1]: b'Unknown command'
```

Comment: Ahh ok, this makes sence. Thanks!